# Undefined reference error while building

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to update my version of rtabmap to the current one on Ubuntu 20.04 with ros noetic. While following the instructions below from [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros):

```
############ rtabmap ###########
$ cd rtabmap
$ git pull origin master
$ cd build
$ make #<-- This is where I get the error
$ make install # Do "sudo make install" if you installed rtabmap in "/usr/local"

############ rtabmap_ros###########
$ roscd rtabmap_ros
$ git pull origin master
$ roscd
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make -j1 --pkg rtabmap_ros
```

At the indicated point, I end up with the following error:

```
(base) zippyzoo77@MountainLion:~/rtabmap/build$ make
[ 4%] Built target rtabmap_utilite
[ 5%] Built target res_tool
[ 42%] Built target rtabmap_core
[ 80%] Built target rtabmap_gui
[ 81%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/rtabmap
/usr/bin/ld: ../../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.20.19: undefined reference to `octomath::Pose6D::Pose6D(octomath::Pose6D const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [app/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap.dir/build.make:243: bin/rtabmap] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:993: app/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
```

I have done all the proper steps and have octomap installed, so I really don't know what could be causing this error. Any help on debugging this so I can get rtabmap up and working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I also get this warning (for over a dozen libraries in the same location) during a previous install step, which I think may be at the root of the problem. What could cause my installation of ROS to be doing this to my files, and how can I fix this?

```
CMake Warning at examples/NoEventsExample/CMakeLists.txt:64 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target noEventsExample
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [liboctomap.so.1.9] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/ros/noetic/lib
    runtime library [liboctomath.so.1.9] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/ros/noetic/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398338/undefined-reference-error-while-building/) by [zippyzoo77](https://answers.ros.org/users/73815/zippyzoo77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-31**:
hey,
if your create the workspace it is `catkin_make` or not?

**Comment by [zippyzoo77](https://answers.ros.org/users/73815/zippyzoo77/) on 2022-04-05**:
Eventually it is catkin_make yes, but that's not where I was running into trouble. I still don't know what was causing this, I eventually ended up just completely uninstalling rtabmap and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had the same error. It seemed I forgot to source my ros installation (where the octomap was installed) before the build.

After I sourced `/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` it built just fine.

---

Originally posted by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) with karma: 194 on 2022-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [efe](https://answers.ros.org/users/134076/efe/) on 2023-01-24**:
where did you source it to by the way?

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2023-01-26**:
To the shell where I run the build command.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2023-01-27**:
More info from this [post](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/issues/737#issuecomment-1407157456):

> On Noetic, another cause is that both liboctomap-dev and ros-noetic-octomap may be installed at the same time (some ros packages depend on the system version, and others on the noetic version). Cleanup rtabmap's build directory, make sure you sourced /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash and redo cmake/make. Rtabmap's cmake should find the version in /opt/ros/noetic first, thus it will work with ros-noetic-octomap-msgs used by rtabmap_ros, and the undefined reference error won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I never did figure out why it was doing this, but I uninstalled and reinstalled rtabmap and now it is working.

---

Originally posted by [zippyzoo77](https://answers.ros.org/users/73815/zippyzoo77/) with karma: 13 on 2022-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1